# Qt 6.3.1 тормозит сборка и отладка под Windows

Tags: qt6

После перехода с Qt 5.15.2 заметно увеличилось время сборки и невероятно дольше стали отображаться значения переменных при отладке по шагам.

Можно на это как-то повлиять?